# Deinterlace tv tuner output in DirectshowNet

Tags: c#, directshow

I am developing a tv tuner capture application in c#. I'm using DirectShowNet for it and my device is AverMedia Super 009. I am using capturegraphbuilder.renderstream() method and i'm using capture pin and not preview pin.
Also I have used vmr9 renderer. But the output i'm getting is interlaced i.e whenever their is motion on the screen, picture appears as toothed edge, so I want to deinterlace it.

On VMR9's input pin I'm getting it's format as 'FORMAT_VideoInfo'. When I checked the "videoHeader.InterlaceFlags & AMInterlace.IsInterlaced", it shows video is not interlaced.
According to whatever i have read on the internet, I cannot deinterlace FORMAT_VideoInfo so, I have to convert it to FORMAT_VideoInfo2. So any one knew the method to convert videoinfo to videoinfo2.

I have also used some Software Deinterlaced Filter like AlparySoft, ffdshow, DScaler. But Still the moving parts appears as toothed edged.

So pls guide me how should I deinterlace the graph.

Thanks,
Ganesh

Comment: If by using the other softwares your picture still IS jagged, something is seriously wrong.

Comment: Hi Danial, May be I'm not using them properly can you tell me how to use and configure them properly.

Answer (score 0):

To convert VideoInfo to VideoInfo2 you'll have to write a DirectShow transform filter which is a tedious task. If you decide to go this way you can start from Contrast example filter from DirectShow SDK (now part of Windows SDK).

Try to save some video to an AVI file and deinterlace it in [VirtualDub](http://www.virtualdub.org/) with many available [deinterlace filters](http://www.infognition.com/VirtualDubFilters/) (like Area-Based or Deinterlace Muxun). If you find one which works well on your video, you can use that filter in your DirectShow app using our [wrapper](http://www.infognition.com/VDFilter/).